# Two part div with scrolling

Tags: html, css

I wish to make a simple two part div:

```
+---------------------+
|  title              |
+---------------------+
|                     |
|   content           |
|                     |
+---------------------+
```

"*Outer*" div must have exactly defined dimensions, for example 400x400 pixels.
"*title*" part must occupy whatever space needed, it is typically about 5-10 percent of height. The "*content*" part can have a lot of content and must be scrolled.

I don't want to use any Javascript.

So far I came with this style:

html:

```
<div class="outer" style="">
  <div class="title">title .... title </div>
  <div class="content"> text text .... text </div>
</div> <!-- outer -->
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    position:relative;
    border:solid red 1px;
}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    top:0;width:100%;
}
.content {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px; /* the problem */
    bottom:0;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

I must manually provide the top border for "*content*" div. So if I change the content of "*title*" div, its height can change and the divs will overlap or not touch.

How do I make those divs correctly resize with their respective content?

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex box, and by specifying `flex-direction` as `column`:

```css
.outer {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
}

.title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="">
  <div class="title">title ....title </div>
  <div class="content">
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
    text text .... text<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove absolute position css from content and title and give max-height to contant so if content will increase than automatically scroll added after some height

```css
.outer {
    width:400px;
    max-height:400px;
    position:relative;
    border:solid red 1px;
}
.title {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    width:100%;
}
.content {
    max-height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer" style="">
  <div class="title">title .... title </div>
  <div class="content"> text text .... text <br/>
text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>text text .... text <br/>  
  
  
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. If title is small, then content is too small too and part of outer box is unused.

Comment: for that you can use max-height:400px; instead of height in .outer  class so if content increase scrollbar add automatically.i changed css please check by increase and reduce content.